# TimelineJs load json from page

Tags: json

is it possible in a TimelineJs instance to load JSON data from a variable in the page?

```
  <div id="timeline-embed"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var timeline_config = {
     width: "100%",
     height: "100%",
     source: 'example_json.json'
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../compiled/js/storyjs-embed.js"></script>
```

this is the default code from the timelineJS example.
Basically i'm trying to replace the `source: 'example_json.json'` with a

```
source: '{
    "timeline":
    {
        "headline":"Sh*t People Say",
        "type":"default",
        "text":"People say stuff",
        "startDate":"2012,1,26",
        "date": [
            {
                "startDate":"2011,12,12",
                "endDate":"2012,1,27",
                "headline":"Vine",
                "text":"<p>Vine Test</p>",
                "asset":
                {
                    "media":"https://vine.co/v/b55LOA1dgJU",
                    "credit":"",
                    "caption":""
                }
            },
            {
                "startDate":"2012,1,26",
                "endDate":"2012,1,27",
                "headline":"Sh*t Politicians Say",
                "text":"<p>In true political fashion, his character rattles off common jargon heard from people running for office.</p>",
                "asset":
                {
                    "media":"http://youtu.be/u4XpeU9erbg",
                    "credit":"",
                    "caption":""
                }
            }
]
    }
}'
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: any updates on this? I'm in the same boat. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing in the JSON object as a string. Remove quotation marks and it should work. Should look like this:

```
    source: {
            "timeline": { 
              ...
            }
    }
```

I've put together a working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FARX4/)